# How can I print mutliple (81) ggplots from a for loop?

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I have a large, long dataset like this example:

```
df <- data.frame("Sample" = c("CM","PB","CM","PB"),"Compound" = c("Hydrogen","Hydrogen","Helium","Helium"), "Value" = c(8,3,3,2))
```

however I have about 162 rows (81 sample/compound pairs)

I am trying to write a loop that prints individual geom_col() plots of each compound where

```
x=Sample
y=Value
```

and there are 81 plots for each compound.

I think I am close with this loop:

I want `i in "each compound"` etc.

```
for (i in df$Compound){
  print(ggplot(data = i),
               aes(x=Sample,
                   y=Value))+
    geom_col()
}
```

What am I missing from this loop? I have also tried facet_wrap(~Compound) However it looks like 81 is too large and each plot is tiny once made. I am looking for a full size bar graph of each compound.

Comment: Thanks fixed the character values

Comment: Thanks, Right, btu the facet makes each plot so small I want each plot full size. I'll mention that I've tried that too.

Comment: `print(ggplot(data=i), aes(...))` is broken, the `aes` is being passed as a second argument to `print` (and not doing what you want). One fix is `print(ggplot(.., aes(..)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues with your code:

- Your `aes` needs to be combined with `ggplot(.)` somehow, not as a second argument to `print`.
- Your `geom_col` needs to be added to the `ggplot(.)` chain, not to `print`.

I think then that your code should be

```r
for (i in df$Compound){
  print(
    ggplot(data = i) +
      aes(x = Sample, y = Value) +
      geom_col()
  )
}
```

A known-working example:

```r
for (CYL in unique(mtcars$cyl)) {
  print(
    ggplot(subset(mtcars, cyl == CYL), aes(mpg, disp)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(title = paste("cyl ==", CYL))
  )
}
```

produces three plots (rapidly).

Note:

1. If you want a break, consider adding `readline("next ...")` after your `print`.
2. I tend to use `gg <- ggplot(..) + ... ; print(gg)` (instead of `print(ggplot(.)+...)`) mostly out of habit, but it can provide a little clarity in errors if/when they occur. It's minor and perhaps more *technique* than anything.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can loop and pull out the selected data set for each index.

```r
for (i in df$Compound){
  print(ggplot(data = df[df$Compound == i,],
               aes(x=Sample,
                   y=Value))+
    geom_col())
}
```

(This code also fixes the problems/misplaced parentheses pointed out by @r2evans)

There are a variety of other ways to do this, e.g. `split()` the data frame by `Compound`, or something tidyverse-ish, or ...